# Using torchmetrics with nan values

Tags: python, deep-learning, metrics, pytorch-lightning, torchmetrics

I'm, working on a a DL project and using pytorch lightning and torchmetrics.

I'm using a metric that is just irrelevant for examples, which means that there exist batches for which this metric will get a NaN value.
The problem is the aggregated value for the function epoch-wise is also computed to be NaN because of that.
Is there a possible workaround? torchmetrics is very convenient and I would like to avoid a switch.

I have seen the `torchmetrics.MeanMetric` object (and similar ones) but I couldn't make it work. If the solution goes through this kind of object I would very much appreciate an example.

Comment: I also have a similar problem. I am also getting NaN values using Kendall Rank Coefficient. NaN values are only present when I use batches. If I load my dataloader with batch = 1  I see no NaN values.